# textView, e.g, can not be selected?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, textview

But, okay this code works for me. I have one question. Why the text em textView, e.g, can not be selected? it does not select text to copy, for example.

this is the code I'm trying to figure out why blocks the selection of the text in view.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: {
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

}, completion: nil)

Comment: One of the animation options you can add is to allow user interaction during the animation (`UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction`). By default this is set to false, so adding this option might solve your problem.

Comment: okay brow..It's work perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this if it is a UITextView:

```
textView.editable = true
textView.selectable = true
```

Comment: You can also set those flags in IB (Interface Builder)

Comment: thanks guys....this solution resolve my problem: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction  By @Sander Saelmans